# Android Studio changes underscore to dash in permission and drops error

Tags: android, permissions, android-studio, manifest

I am trying to insert

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to my permissions.
When I try to build my project, android studio changes the underscores of ONLY THIS permission to dashes and tells me "sorry dude, no dashes in here, please"...

```
Error:(15) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character '-'.
```

The other permissions like

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```

are working well WITH the underscores...

Does anyone know, what is going on here? 
Thank you!!

**EDIT**

For those how didn't read the comments:
The problem is fixed.

I know, the question is not as helpful as others, but i won't delete it, because somebody will someday have the same issue, that he has opened up a file twice and errors are happening... I hope, in case, it will help.

Merry Christmas. ;)

Comment: `Very Strange Error!!!!! `

Comment: It is... Do you have an idea?

Comment: Can you post the whole AndroidManifest.xml please.

Comment: Ok, fixed it. The reason was as strange as the error.

I had accidentally opend up androidmanifest.xml twice. (Which is actually not possible. Perhaps I found a bug. Can't reproduce it.) I closed the one which was throwing the error, built it and it worked.

Sorry for my "awesomeness"! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens because `AndroidManifest.xml` was opened twice.

Answer (score -1):

Go to "File" and click "Invalidate caches / restart".